# I am having an error:Expected end Sub in writing a Macro to transfer data from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me.

I am having an error in writing a Macro to transfer data from Excel to Word.
The Macro is:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       Sub CopyToWord()

        Dim objWord As New Word.Application
        Range("A1:B10").Copy

        With objWord
            .Documents.Add
            .Selection.Paste
            .Visible = True
        End With

    End Sub
 End Sub
```

and the error is

Compile Error: Expected End Sub

I don't know whats the problem as I am not missing End sub.

Please guide
Thanks.

Comment: You still have a sub inside a sub.  Remove the `Sub CopyToWord()`

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I correct it?

Comment: if the intent is to call another sub within this sub, you can simply get rid of the keyword `Sub` from in front of `CopyToWord`, though by the looks of it, you'll want to scrap that line entirely.

Comment: Actually I just want to transfer data from excel sheet to word thats it

Comment: Then simply delete the second line of your example code, and you should be good.

Comment: If I removes the sub, from CopytoWord () . I still receiving error.

Comment: Edit the post and include the new error you're seeing.  May be something else wrong with the code, I'm unfortunately not that familiar with excel vba specifically.

Comment: As per your directions, Now I have just this code     

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application

    Range("A1:B10").Copy

    With objWord
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Visible = True
    End With
    
End Sub

Comment: Now the error is User defined type not defined

Comment: Remove the whole line `Sub CopyToWord()` it is not needed, the sub is called with the click.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're trying to use requires the `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` (or whatever else version number), without it you'll get a `user-defined type not defined`). Just use late-binding instead (where you declare `objWord` as an `Object` instead, then `Set` it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Range("A1:B10").Copy

With objWord
    .Documents.Add
    .Selection.Paste
    .Visible = True
End With

Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have one more question, in this way the copied cells are pasted to a new document. that's fine.
But now my question is:
Is it possible to paste the data at the end or any where in an existing Word document?

Comment: The better choice would be to add a reference to the Microsoft Word object library (**Tools** -> **References...**), instead of using late binding.

Comment: @Zev Spitz could you please tell me? how can I do that?

Comment: @Shozib **Tools** -> **References...** from the VBA editor window, and select Microsoft Word object library. As I noted in my previous comment.